Correct way for a custom 404 page in Nginx?
What is the correct way to show a custom 404 page for non-existing subdomains in Nginx?
My current approach is to provide a 404 page for every subdomain, and then define an another separate configuration for every single subdomain. The result is, that it somewhat works, somewhat meaning it works in the Chrome incognito-mode, same for Firefox, but it does not work with the Samsung Android Browser, neither does it work in Apple's Safari, or in the non-incognito-mode. I think it has to do that i.e. Chrome in incognito-mode calls the HTTP page when calling examplesubdomain.example.com while when in non-incognito-mode Chrome calls the HTTPS variant. Due to the fact that I do not have a correct HTTPS-certificate for every subdomain i.e. examplesubdomain, I get the error "Your connection is not private". What must I do to get the 404 HTML page instead?
I do run Docker containers in the background that I proxy the subdomains to. Just for clarification.
Here is the 404-configuration for Nginx:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;

    root /var/www/404/public_html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name *.example.com;

    include ssl/ssl_example.com.conf;
    include ssl/ssl_all_sites.conf;

    root /var/www/404/public_html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

And here is the configuration for the general domain:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    include ssl/ssl_example.com.conf;
    include ssl/ssl_all_sites.conf;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/include/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

The definition for a subdomain looks like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/mysubdomain.example.com/public_html;
    index index.html;
    server_name mysubdomain.example.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/mysubdomain.example.com/public_html;
    index index.html;
    server_name mysubdomain.example.com;

    include ssl/ssl_mysubdomain.example.com.conf;
    include ssl/ssl_all_sites.conf;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/include/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
    }
}


Are you assuming that your 404-configuration affects how the general and subdomain configurations behave? Because Nginx does not work like that. Nginx selects a single server block to process a request.
